# What should i use after OpenNI down?

Tags: kinect, openni

As we know,the OpenNI and openni.org have been closed. But I need to use Kinect or Xtion to make a 3D scanner. what should I use now? I find that structure.io provides OpenNI 2, but I am not sure if it is compatible with those codes or driver using OpenNI.

Comment: What's wrong with the official APIs?

Comment: it seems that Apple closed the openni.org so there may be some risks to use the old APIs?

Comment: You can still get openni and openni2 from the original source [here](https://github.com/OpenNI?tab=repositories). What you can not obtain anymore from the original source is NiTe... As far as I know the openni2 offered by structure.io is the original packages and they are only hosting it since it can be used with their cameras

Comment: Thank you for your tips. As far as I know NiTe is for Body Tracking.Is that means I actually don't need it if I only focus on 3D reconstruction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use Kinect SDKs provided by Microsoft. You can definitely access all the functionality and there are many resources out there to get a quick start. I did a virtual dressing room project using only Kinect SDKs and XNA.

Comment: You mean SDK 1.8 or 2.0 ?It seems that 2.0 can only work with kinect v2 and windows 8. But I have a kinect for xbox and windows 7?

Comment: you can use sdk 1.7 with win 8 n 7.

Comment: since you are new to stackoverflow and if you are satisfied with my answer you can accept by clicking the right mark this helps to increase the chance of getting an answer for your future questions.